# VSE animated mask with scenes?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, transparency, masking

Ok so in a nutshell, I want to make a video that has 2 pictures that overlap eachother, and the overlap is animated, like this:

[image]

The clips are in the VSE:[image: The VSE]

And the blend file(with photos): https://www.dropbox.com/s/xiztxtvxtzmvm5n/Unicycle.zip?dl=0
But I want to add in a black line right where the 2 clips meet.
Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hard edge built in to the wipe effect. Only blur width. You could make a  black bar .PNG then use the Transform effect to rotate it at the same time. You could use this addon http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?280731-VSE-Transform-tool it makes interacting withe the VSE transforms much easier.

Comment: So what I want to do is make a black line as an object in a different scene, and have the line have the same animation as the mask

Comment: Thats right. But you could make the line with the transform effect applied to a color strip, by scaling it down vertically then rotating it.

Comment: Ohhhh. Ok that makes sense. Thanks for the help!